# Google app script : Separating HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

i have a question connected with title. Currently i am trying to follow google "best practice". https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices
I have no idea why its not working.
Here is a MainPageCSS.html

```
<pre>
<style>
p {
  color: green;
}
</style>
</pre>
```

Then comes server-side function:

```
function includeCSS() { 
var content = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('MainPageCSS').getRawContent();
  //.getContent();
return content;
}
```

I am using a sidebar via HtmlService, and calling google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(SuccessAddCss).includeCSS();
I tried different ways of adding css into page, but noone worked...

```
function SuccessAddCss(Style){
   var styles = document.getElementById("allStyles").innerHTML += "p { color:red }";
   var text = styles.innerHTML;
   var styleNode = document.createElement('style');
   var styleText = document.createTextNode('p { color:red; } ');
   styleNode.appendChild(styleText);
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);
   alert("ok");
};
function teso()
{
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(SuccessAddCss).includeCSS();
   alert(text);
};
```

In order to add somehow css from MainPageCSS to MainPage
id="allStyles" type="text/css"

```
<pre>
<style id="allStyles" type="text/css">
h2{
font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

</pre>
```

Also sidebar is launched in SandBox.Native mode, so it allows css dynamic changes.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my website, I use a scriptlet to include the CSS file.

### HTML:

```
<?!= include('MainPageCSS'); ?>

<div>Some Content Here</div>
<form>A form</form>
<button>A button</button>
```

That's how the `include` function gets called from the HTML file.  Just curious, could you try taking out the `<pre>` tags and see if that makes any difference?